# ambiguity in String startswith the given string

Tags: c#, string

I need to see if string starts with a given string but I am getting ambiguity, here is my code:

```
string input = "balance1234";

string[] arr = new string[]
{
    "bal",
    "balance",
};

foreach (string s in arr)
{
    if (input.StartsWith(s))
    {
        var rq= input.Replace(s, "");
    }
}
```

If input is *balance1234* , the `if` condition has to satisfy only with `balance`, but in my code it is satisfying with `bal` first.

Comment: So what have you *tried* to do to fix it? Hint: if you sort your array in descending order of length, then the first leading substring to match will have to be the longest one...

Comment: Why do have 'bal' as the first item in array if you do not want it to be matched?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out a generic method to solve the use case

Comment: Are you trying to make a generic function to fix this?

Comment: If the array is coming from database how can i sort it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution (using the Hint given by Mr. Skeet):

```
string input = "balance1234";

string[] arr = new string[]
{
    "bal",
    "balance",
};

string rq = input;
foreach (string s in arr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))
{
    if (input.StartsWith(s))
    {
        rq = input.Replace(s, "");
        break;
    }
}
```